# simple reshape in R using reshape2 causes error

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, reshape2

I am trying to do a simple `reshape` to make `test` look like this:

```
a_estimate, a_tstat, b_estimate, b_tstat
1,          3,       2,          4
```

This is the code I try:

```
require(reshape2)
test = data.frame(cf=c("a", "b"), estimate=c(1,2), tstat=c(3,4))
m = melt(test, id.vars="cf")
d = dcast(m, formula = . ~ cf + variable)
Error: nrow(res$labels[[1]]) == nrow(data) is not TRUE
```

What's going on here?

```
> sessionInfo()    
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.2.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] plyr_1.8      stringr_0.6.2
```

Comment: If the objective is to recover `test` from `m` then you want: `dcast(m, cf ~ variable, value.var = "value")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: not sure i follow, the objective is to make test look like the second line of the question.

Comment: Try this: `dcast(m, 1 ~ cf + variable)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you have effectively zero "row" variables left (i.e., you don't want anything at all on the LHS of the casting formula).  This workaround (adding a dummy variable) might help?

```
d = dcast(cbind(x=1,m), formula = x ~ cf + variable)
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is *technically* a bug -- one would have to look closely at the specifications/documentation to see if the zero-variables left case is discussed at all.  If it's not mentioned, then it's "undefined behaviour" rather than a bug ... (The software not doing what you want, in a case the designer didn't consider, doesn't necessarily constitute a bug.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's the base R way, for fun...

```
reshape(transform(test, id=1), idvar='id', timevar='cf', direction='wide')[-1]
#   estimate.a tstat.a estimate.b tstat.b
# 1          1       3          2       4
```

Comment: thanks! i was hoping to stick to the package since i'm used to it but i should use base R functionality when possible.